# Docker port mapping and redirects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**The context**

I have set up a docker container for my wordpress website, which I am deploying with the following command.

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=docker-compose-dev.yml portfolio_dev
```

My docker-compose-dev.yml has the following:

```
services:
  nginx:
    networks:
      - nginx
    configs:
      - source: nginx_config
        target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
```

**The problem**

When I visit http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php I get the wordpress login form, but it is not loading styles because it is looking for them in http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php which doesn't exist.

**The question**

How do I ensure docker uses the correct URL's for my stylesheets? I should mention I am on a mac and have MAMP PRO installed on my computer which has some custom port changes.

Comment: what is your root directory in nginx conf file?

Comment: I've discovered the issue was in fact the wrong URL in the wordpress database. Thank you for the question though!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the URL in the wordpress database was the issue! The default is localhost which I updated to localhost:8888 and now everything works as expected. Some times it's the most obvious thing people!